# Can IPV4 address exist between an IPV6 range?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, subnet

I'm relatively new to the IP Address concept and trying to build a range checker.

USE CASE: The user gives one IP Address(can be IPv4/IPv6) and a range(can be 2 IPv4 addresses /2 IPv6 addresses/ 1 IPv4 and 1 IPv6 address).

I need to test if the given IP exists between the specified range.

I just wanted to know if the below cases are possible

1. Can an IPv4 address exist between 2 IPv6 addresses?
2. Can an IPv6 address exist between 2 IPv4 addresses?
3. Can an IP range be 1 IPV4 address and 1 IPv6 address or do IP ranges implicitly mean the same types(like fromIPv4 - toIPv4, fromIPv6 - toIPv6)?

Note:  When talking about IPv6 addresses, I mean all IPv6 addresses and not just those that can be mapped to IPv4.

Comment: This question is off-topic since it is apparently about networks and how they work ... not programming.  But it doesn't make any sense.  IPv4 and IPv6 are separate "spaces", so the whole question appears to be based on a misconception.  (The short answers are 1) No, 2) No, 3) the latter.)

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate, incompatible protocols with different addressing. IPv4 addresses are 32-bit, unsigned integers, IPv6 addresses are 128-bit, unsigned integers, and IPX addresses are 96 bits. None of those protocols have anything to do with the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPV6 and IPV4 is two different protocols, that don't intersect at all

Just check what pattern IPV4 matches and what pattern IPV6 matches

IPV4 consist of four parts, each part has value from 0-255 and separated with dot.

IPV6 consist of 8 octets, separated with colon sign.

And main reason, why it's unreal to find out, is that IPV4 use netmask for dividing IP address on network part and host part

At the same time IPV6 address is strictly divided on Routing prefix and interface id

Comment: Actually, an IPv4 address is a 32-bit, unsigned integer. The dotted decimal notation is simply to make it easier for humans, but the four octets mean nothing to IPv4. IPv6 addresses are 128-bit, unsigned integers, and the text notation on eight 16-bit words (not octets) is one of three ways to notate IPv6 addresses for humans, and it is meaningless to IPv6.

Comment: Yep, my fault. I forgot that IP addresses could be translated into bit-for-bit view. I have talked more about IPV4/6 addresses representation in human-reading format. So, yes, IP addresses are not comparable also because of amount of bits that used for each IP version.